# Why is EMF = I(R+r)?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

A voltmeter is connected to a dry cell battery. The voltmeter reads 9 V. A 24Ω resistor is connected across the terminals of the battery and the voltmeter reading becomes 7.2 V. Calculate the internal resistance of the cell.

Solution:

The circuit:

[image]

We assume the voltmeter draws no current, so in the first experiment we are measuring the EMF of the cell i.e. E = 9.0V.
  
When we connect a 24Ω resistor we now have a circuit with the 9V cell, the internal resistance r and the external 24Ω resistor.

The voltage measured across the cell is now 7.2V, so that means we have 7V across the 24Ω resistor and therefore the current is I = V/R = 7.2/24 = 0.3A.

Now, for internal resistance:

Equation 1: 9 - 7.2 = 0.3 * r

Equation 2 I am not sure how to write:

$$7.2 = 0.3(24+r) or 9 = 0.3(24+r) $$

I prefer the first; let’s consider the above diagram with arrows as the path for current. Then, the current travels through both the cell and the 24ohm resistor. The internal resistance is present only when there is current flow i.e. when V = 7.2.

Why is the second equation right?

Comment: Why do you need 2 equations, if you can use one already?

Comment: @Justme I want to understand every equation. Equation 1 is directly using formula from Textbook & equation 2 , I thought of on my own.

Comment: But in equation 2 , i see two types. Therefore , I want to correct where am I wrong.

Comment: @Justme Also , for equation  1. I have to check more to understand why is the formula v = I*r but right now , my Q is different.

Comment: Well use KCL and KVL. If you start looking at voltages in the loop, and go around the loop checking for voltage changes, everything must add up so that after completing the loop you are at same potential you left with. So they can't both be correct.

Comment: "The internal resistance is present only when there is current flow" No, the internal resistance is always present.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  K. Then , why in my 2nd equation , 1st part is wrong & 2nd is right ?

Comment: The first option for Equation 2 is invalid because the 7.2 V is measured across the 24 Ω resistor - it's incorrect to include r here. The second option is correct because it equates the EMF source with the voltage drops around the entire circuit. (This is KVL if you haven't encountered it yet.)

Comment: "the internal resistance is always present" It only has an effect if current flows through it causing a voltage drop. Your ideal voltmeter takes no current and causes no voltage drop in the internal resistance. Hence it reads the EMF.

Comment: @GrahamNye For The second option , When we consider EMF , current = 0. Then , I will have to equate I = 0 & not 0.3 ?

Comment: "When we consider EMF , current = 0" No. The EMF is always 9 V irrespective of how much current, or none, is flowing. When the 24 Ω resistor is connected to the battery 0.3 A will flow, as you calculated, and the EMF is still 9 V. So the second option for equation 2 is correct as written: 9 = 0.3(24+r). You have 2 valid equations for r so you can give us your value for r and we'll check it for you.

Comment: " I have to check more to understand why is the formula v = I*r " That's [Ohm's Law](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-2/voltage-current-resistance-relate/). It's a fundamental rule for analysing circuits. Scroll down the link to the heading "Ohm’s Law Triangle Technique". It's worth memorising that triangle and how to use it to remember the 3 equivalent versions of Ohm's Law. (You may see it written with E for EMF or V for Voltage. In this context they are equivalent.)

Comment: @GrahamNye I have created a room on electrical engineering stack exchange for us to have a discussion on this Q. Please do join.

Comment: Name is ‘ Room for SMT & Graham’.

Comment: I can't see a chat room in the aging Android SE app I use. It will be sometime late this evening (UTC TZ) before I can check from a desktop PC. I encourage you to ask here for a faster response and a wider range of advice. It will still be useful for you to post your calculated value of r so someone can check your understanding.

Comment: To help anyone who is interested, the direct link to the chatroom mentioned above is here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131582/chat-between-smt-graham

Comment: I've added a comment in the chatroom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to help you when you write your equations with no symbols or units. Your second equation seems to indicate that
$$V_R = I_{\text{total}} \cdot (R+r) $$
which is **clearly wrong**. Your third equation indicates
$$V_{\text{total}} = I_{\text{total}} \cdot (R+r) $$
which is correct. Hopefully you can see why. From that, you can deduce what \$r \$ should be.

You should get into a habit of first writing a symbolic equation, and then plug in values **with units**. That way, you can also see if terms cancel out, reducing the computation you have to perform.